# Dynamic structures

Tags: c, dynamic, structure

I have the following problem with the code, this is dropped in this function:

```
int EliminarRelacion() {

struct amigos *ancla=primero, *ant=NULL;
char user1[12], user2[12];
int i=1;

printf("Nombre usuario 1: "); scanf("%s", &user1);
printf("Nombre usuario 2: "); scanf("%s", &user2);

while(ancla!=NULL) {
    if(i>=2) { //Guarda la posición anterior a ancla
        if(i==1)
            ant = primero;
        else
            ant = ant->siguiente;
    }

    if(!(strcmp(ancla->usuario1, user1) && strcmp(ancla->usuario2, user2))) {
        ant->siguiente = ancla->siguiente;
        //free(ancla->usuario1);
        //free(ancla->usuario2);
        free(ancla);
        printf("Eliminado...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ancla = ancla->siguiente;
    i++;
}

if(i==1)
    printf("%c NO EXISTEN AMISTADES ACTUALMENTE %c\n", 16, 17);

return 0;

}
```

This code seeks to eliminate (free dynamic memory) somewhere in the structure indicated by the user keyboard.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: In the function int EliminarRelacion(), the program falls to find the item to be deleted.

Comment: The code fragment `if(i>=2) {
        if(i==1)
            ant = primero;
        else
            ant = ant->siguiente;
    }` is peculiar; the `ant = primero;` line will never be executed because `i` is not 1 when it is `>= 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code what I see is,

```
printf("Nombre usuario 1: "); scanf("%s", &user1);
                                          ^--------------Here
printf("Nombre usuario 2: "); scanf("%s", &user2);
                                          ^--------------Here
```

The `scanf` function takes address of a variable, and you are trying to input a string.
By mentioning the name of the array `user1` or `user2` you will get the address. But you are passing `&user1` and `&user2` as parameter to `scanf` function.

If the logic for finding the item to be delete is proper, and you change the code

```
printf("Nombre usuario 1: "); scanf("%s", user1);
printf("Nombre usuario 2: "); scanf("%s", user2);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

People, I've found the problem.
In the condition:

```
if((strcmp(anchor->user1, user1) && strcmp (anchor->user2, user2)))
```

should be:

```
if((strcmp(anchor->user1, user1)==0) && (strcmp(anchor->user2, user2)==0))
```

The program was shutting down when entering for the first time.

Thank you all!